# Attachment downloaded as type file

Tags: apex, attachment, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have below code to add content document versionData into standard attachment.

```
    Map<Id, Blob> bodyContent = new Map<Id, Blob>();
    List<ContentVersion> contentDocs =  [SELECT Id, Description, title,versionData,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN : contentIds];
    for(ContentVersion cVersion : contentDocs){
         bodyContent.put(cVersion.ContentDocumentId,cVersion.versionData);
    }

    for (ContentVersion attach : contentDocs) {
           Attachment conAttach = new Attachment();
           conAttach.ParentId = customAttach.Id;
           conAttach.Name = attach.title;
           conAttach.Body = bodyContent.get(attach.ContentDocumentId);
           conAttach.Description = attach.Id;
           attachmentListToInsert.add(conAttach);
    }
```

I have created the standard attachment with contentDocument versionData successfully. But when I download the attachment it is downloaded as type file.

[image]

**But I want to download the file extension**. Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: you probably need to append the `FileExtension` value to the filename, e.g. `conAttach.Name = attach.Title + '.' + attach.FileExtension`

Answer (score 0):

[How can I compose a multipart/form-data request?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request/132136)

Try like this.

Encode your contentversion data and convert as a blob

```
String strVersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cntver.VersionData);
Blob bBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(strVersionData);
```

Comment: Hi Raja vel,,  Thank you.. But still it is not working as expected. It downloaded as file type

Comment: get filetype like below...ContentDocument cntdoc = [Select Id,Title,OwnerId,ParentId,FileExtension,FileType,CreatedDate,
                                  ContentSize,CreatedById,LatestPublishedVersionId from ContentDocument 
                                  where Id=:DocumentId];   Contentversion cntver = [select Id,VersionData,FileType from contentversion 
                                 where Id=:cntdoc.LatestPublishedVersionId];