# How to give Content Type while downloading attachment from url?

Tags: apex, lightning, attachment

I am trying to download attachment from link :

```
<a href="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+attachment.Id}" target="_blank">{!attachment.name}</a>
```

but the attachment is being downloaded as type "file". I have tried to append Content Type with file name while saving the file but it doesn't seem to be working.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
p.s - a question is already asked on similar topic ([click here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252862/attachment-downloaded-as-type-file)) but answers were not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "download" attribute, provide the filename of the attachment there (make sure it includes the extension).

```
<a href="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+attachment.Id}" download="{!attachment.name}" target="_blank">{!attachment.name}</a>
```

*"download" attribute info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp*