# How to upload an image as a binary file via the Linkedin API v2 with a 'POST' request

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, json, linkedin

I want to know how to make a proper 'POST' request to upload an image as a binary file to Linkedin via their API. This is what they say in their documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context):

> Using the uploadUrl returned from Step 1, upload your image to LinkedIn. To upload your image, send a POST request to the uploadUrl with your image included as a binary file.

They then proceed to give an example using cURL but I need to make an HTTP request from my Apex code so I need the json format of the request body.

To further illustrate my point, these are the steps to post an image in Linkedin through their API:

> 1) Register your image to be uploaded.
>
> 2) Upload your image to LinkedIn.
>
> 3) Create the image share.

They provide the json for steps 1 and 3 but not for 2, hence my problem.

This is the part of the code I consider relevant, should you need any other part just tell me so and I will edit my question:

```
        httpReq.setMethod('POST');
        httpReq.setEndpoint(uploadUrl);
        httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+linkedlnInfoListNew[0].Access_Token__c);        
        httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/binary');             
        httpReq.setHeader('X-Restli-Protocol-Version', '2.0.0');
        requestBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(banner);
        httpReq.setBody(requestBody);
```

The uploadUrl variable is the URL provided in the response of step 1. As it is, this request produces no response body and has a status: created and status code: 201

**I have tried the following**:

- Perform a 'PUT' request instead of a 'POST'.
- Different 'Content-Type' headers but decided on the one showed in the code above because of the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789489/linkedin-api-v2-how-to-upload-photo-as-binary-file
- requestBody = '{' +
                   'data:' + requestBodyImage +
               '}'; The variable requestBodyImage would be the image binary.

To summarize, I just want to know what to put in the body of the 'POST' request mentioned in step 2 of the Linkedin API documentation on how to share an image.

EDIT: It would also be helpful if someone knows the answer to this problem but instead of using the binary of the image they use an url referencing the image.

EDIT 21/07/19: This is the image I am currently trying to share on Linkedin.

[image]

This is the updated http request with its headers:

```
    httpReq.setEndpoint(uploadUrl);
    httpReq.setBodyAsBlob(formBlob);        
    httpReq.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    httpReq.setMethod('POST');
    httpReq.setTimeout(120000);             //These are all the attributes that are set in the example.

    httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+linkedlnInfoListNew[0].Access_Token__c);            
    //httpReq.setHeader('x-li-format' , 'json');
    httpReq.setHeader('X-Restli-Protocol-Version', '2.0.0');
```

The *formBlob* variable is the blob of the image constructed using the code provided in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request).

And this is the response given after the request above:

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Request Entity Too Large, StatusCode=413]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type needs to be [multipart/form-data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares); there are also other requirements (see docs). This is difficult to do in Apex but [possible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request). You should vote up this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Kr80AAC).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was using [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) to share the image. What's the difference between the rich media share and the image share in the documentation I was using? For both scenarios I have the same question: in both it says to make a post request to a certain address but they do not specify what to include in the body of said request. Do you know this?

Comment: Uploading an image via [Rich Media Share API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares) is one step of the overall share sequence. The entire sequence is described in the [Share on LinkedIn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) doc you've referenced.

Comment: When trying to upload rich media using the API it says I don't have permission to do it. Investigating a bit further I found out that I need permission directly from Linkedin to do this. I find this very weird as nowhere in the documentation is mentioned this. It says that I need the "w_member_social" to post on behalf of an authenticated member, which I do have. Therefore, I tried uploading the file as instructed in the [Share on Linkedin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) doc but I got an error...

Comment: ... saying the file was too big. So, I reduced the size of the image to half and I still get the same error which is quite baffling as the image is reasonably small. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zufra As this issue isn't Salesforce specific, I recommend posting a new question with a trace of your request/response on StackOverflow rather than here

Comment: Already posted in StackOverflow the same question but had no answers. I know it is not Salesforce specific but it sure will come in handy for anyone trying to make a Salesforce integration with Linkedin in the future if this problem is solved.

Comment: @Zufra Fair enough. In that case, please edit your question and provide the trace along with the image you're trying to upload.

Comment: I assumed that by trace you meant the error shown when trying to share the image. If so, then you will find this edited in the question. Thanks for your time @identigral .

Comment: Trace = HTTP request + response, including headers and body.

Comment: Done, if there is anything missing please let me know.

Comment: Your Apex code sending HTTP request looks nothing like the example I referenced in my answer

Comment: On the contrary, it is exactly like the one you referenced. I just added some headers and changed some things to adapt it to a Linkedin integration rather than an integration with Kraken.io. The only new headers are the ones at the end of the code sample I edited into the question and they are needed to use the Linkedin API.
The formBlob variable that is assigned as the body of the request is created using the methods in the "vNHttpFormBuilder" class shown in the example you referenced. Why are you saying my code is "nothing like the example"?

Comment: The example prepares multipart encoding, then creates an instance of HttpRequest with file as a blob. The code you provided doesn't show how you build content-type, content-length and values of uploadUrl and fileBlob. Instead of "looks nothing like", I should have said "it's missing the important multipart pieces" Perhaps you have them in your code but it's unclear on what you're doing.

Comment: Both “content-type” and “content-length” are created like in the example you referenced. So is formBlob. The uploadUrl is the one provided by LinkedIn as specified in the first step of “image share” in this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add a comment with a suggestion but it says it is too long. So my answer is not based on the fact that I got this working. It's simply an answer to your "what to put in the body of the 'POST' request mentioned in step 2" part. Will leave it to you to validate if it works.

I tried to find the HTTP request details from that curl example by appending the `--trace-ascii /dev/stdout` args. It gives me this request details (I used a smaller size image):

```
0000: PUT /mediaUpload/C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?c
0040: a=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQJbrN86Zm265gAAAWemyz2pxPSgONtB
0080: iZdchrgG872QltnfYjnMdb2j3A&app=1953784&sync=0&v=beta&ut=2H-Ihpbf
00c0: XrRow1 HTTP/2
00cf: Host: api.linkedin.com
00e7: User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
0100: Accept: */*
010d: Authorization: Bearer redacted
012d: Content-Length: 28596

== Info: Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
=> Send data, 16384 bytes (0x4000)

0000: .PNG
0006: ......IHDR..............x......sBIT....|.d.....pHYs..........+..
0046: ....tEXtSoftware.www.inkscape.org..<... .IDATx...w.\.y7..s..>...
0086: #.*.It..#!......%ny.&q..I^G...M\b...0.cl.06H.M....$.z...j....{..
......
```

So the HTTP method that curl example uses is `PUT`. That body seems to be the string representation of the binary data with the first line `.PNG` denoting its file type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the posting by below code snippet. I used Content-Type as application/binary and request body as Blob file content.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/binary');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(uploadURL);
req.setBodyAsBlob(blob_file_body); //blob file content
req.setTimeout(120000);
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accToken);   
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```