# Error received: {"document":["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."],"status_code":400}

Tags: apex, callout

I'm trying to do a POST call to SBA from Salesforce that involves uploading a file.  The call asks for 4 parameters in the form of JSON.   As I have tested, 3 of the 4 JSON fields are passing validation on the other end.  However, when I use the VersionData(Blob) field on the ContentVersion, the error in the title is returned.  I have also tried using PathOnClient(String) as the value, but receive the same error.

Perhaps there is another field on the ContentVersion object that I should be passing in to represent the file? Or maybe there is another object I should be using to retrieve the file and utilize it in Apex?  My sandbox is fairly new so the Attachment object unfortunately doesn't retrieve any files via SOQL.  **My code is below:**

```
public static void makeCallOutForUpload(){
    
    //query for File
    ContentVersion file = [SELECT Title, PathOnClient, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = '0693J0000007rltQAA' AND IsLatest = true];
    
    
    //sample request for upload doc callout
    String jsonstring = '{'
                       +'"name": "delete these todos.csv",'
                       +'"document": "'+file.VersionData+'",'
                       +'"document_type": "1",'
                       +'"etran_loan": "7ab138f3-7507-47f9-a330-1a2c0b4e4f73"'
                       + '}';
  
    HttpResponse response;
    ETranDetails__c etranDetails = ETranDetails__c.getOrgDefaults();
    
    //call out logic here
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setHeader('Authorization', etranDetails.API_Key__c);
    request.setHeader('Vendor-Key', etranDetails.Vendor_Key__c);
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setEndpoint(etranDetails.Forgiveness_Endpoint_For_Upload_Docs__c);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setTimeout(120000);
    request.setBody(jsonstring);
    response = http.send(request);
    
    system.debug('what came back?'+response.getStatusCode()+' '+response.getBody());
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of an unnamed source and these links:

http://enreeco.blogspot.com/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html

[How can I compose a multipart/form-data request?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request)

, I was able to figure it out.  Here is the code that returned back a positive response:

```
Public Static blob build_SBA_Blob(string fileName, string docID, string eTranSlug, blob contVers) {
            
        //query for File
        ContentVersion file = [SELECT Title, PathOnClient, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = '0693J0000007xV8QAI' AND IsLatest = true];
            
         docID = '3'; 
         eTranSlug = 'etran number';
         fileName = file.PathOnClient; 
         contVers = file.VersionData;   
            
        //STEP X1: Create the header of the form-data
        system.debug('STEP X1: Create the header of the form-data');
        string strHeader;
        strHeader =  '--1ff13444ed8140c7a32fc4e6451aa76d\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n'+fileName;
        strHeader += '\r\n--1ff13444ed8140c7a32fc4e6451aa76d\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document_type\"\r\n\r\n'+docID;
        strHeader += '\r\n--1ff13444ed8140c7a32fc4e6451aa76d\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"etran_loan\"\r\n\r\n'+eTranSlug;
        strHeader += '\r\n--1ff13444ed8140c7a32fc4e6451aa76d\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document\"; filename=\"' + fileName + '\"\r\n\r\n';
        system.debug(strHeader);
        //STEP X2: Remove padding spaces from header
        system.debug('STEP X2: Remove padding spaces from header');
        String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(strHeader));
        while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='))
        {
           strHeader+=' ';
           headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(strHeader));
        }
        //STEP X3: Create the body and footer, handling the padding spaces
        system.debug('STEP X3: Create the body and footer, handling the padding spaces');
        string strFooter = '--1ff13444ed8140c7a32fc4e6451aa76d--'; 
        String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contVers);
               Blob bodyBlob = null;
               String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
         // GW: replacement section to get rid of padding without corrupting data
         if(last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
            system.debug('last4Bytes.endsWith(\'==\')');
            // The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only one 8 bit byte
            // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
            // 8 digit binary representation of LF is 00001010
            // Stitch them together and then from the right split them into 6 bit chunks
            // 0000110100001010 becomes 0000 110100 001010
            // Note the first 4 bits 0000 are identical to the padding used to encode the
            // second original 6 bit chunk, this is handy it means we can hard code the response in
            // The decimal values of 110100 001010 are 52 10
            // The base64 mapping values of 52 10 are 0 K
            // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for base64 mapping table
            // Therefore, we replace == with 0K
            // Note: if using nn instead of rn replace == with 'oK'
            last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
            bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
            // We have appended the rn to the Blob, so leave footer as it is.
            String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(strFooter));
            //PUT IT ALL TOGETHER IN THE BLOB
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
          } else if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
            system.debug('last4Bytes.endsWith(\'=\')');
            // '=' indicates that encoded data already contained two out of 3x 8 bit bytes
            // We replace final 8 bit byte with a CR e.g. r
            // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
            // Ignore the first 2 bits of 00 001101 they have already been used up as padding
            // for the existing data.
            // The Decimal value of 001101 is 13
            // The base64 value of 13 is N
            // Therefore, we replace = with N
            // Note: if using n instead of r replace = with 'K'
            last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
            bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
            // We have appended the CR e.g. r, still need to prepend the line feed to the footer
            strFooter = 'n' + strFooter;
            String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(strFooter));
            //PUT IT ALL TOGETHER IN THE BLOB
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);             
          } else {
            system.debug('else');
            // Prepend the CR LF to the footer
            strFooter = 'rn' + strFooter;
            String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(strFooter));
            //PUT IT ALL TOGETHER IN THE BLOB
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded); 
          }
            
      ETranDetails__c etranDetails = ETranDetails__c.getOrgDefaults();
            
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; charset="UTF-8"; boundary="1ff13444ed8140c7a32fc4e6451aa76d"');
      req.setHeader('Authorization', etranDetails.API_Key__c);
      req.setHeader('Vendor-Key', etranDetails.Vendor_Key__c);      
      req.setMethod('POST');
      req.setEndpoint(etranDetails.Forgiveness_Endpoint_For_Upload_Docs__c);
      req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
      req.setTimeout(120000);
            
      Http http = new Http();
      HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);      
            
      system.debug('what came back?'+res.getStatusCode()+' '+res.getBody());      
            
        return bodyBlob;
    }
```