# Technical Feasibility - converting a CURL to Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, einstein

Caveat, I am very unfamiliar with APEX and coding in general.

Objective:
I am trying to post to Einstein Named Entity Recognizer API. The docs provide this curl example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "document=Marc Benioff, the CEO of Salesforce, gave the keynote speech at the conference in Paris last week." https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/entities
```

I have successfully posted to it from the command line using my OAuth token with solid results.
I am now trying to add it to a lightning flow and need to make it a Apex Class so i can call it.

I've been looking thought this site and can't determine a coding sample so allow me to achieve success.

I did attempt this based on looking at other's code for the Vision API but i'm not encoding Base64.

1/24/21
EXAMPLE CODE:

<<<UPDATE 1/25/based on comments>>>
Thank you for the response Prashanth.

I updated the two classes as follows (based on the links you provided):
mycode (form builder):

```
public class NERFormBuilder {
    // source code from: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request]
    // Creating a header with values with values for Authorization, Cache-Control
    // Content-Type and a Form value of document
    // private final static is the statement for a constant
    
    //  OAuth token timeout is 3600 minutes.
    private final static string Token = 'value here'; 
    
    
    /**
*  Returns the request's Authorization.
*/
    public static string GetAuthType() {
        return 'Bearer ' + Token;
    }
```

my code Response:

```
private NERResponse Submit(
    NERRequest request,
    string url,
    string security,
    string fileName,
    string fileMimeType,
    blob fileBlob) {
        try {
            string contentType = NERFormBuilder.GetContentType();
            string json = GetJson(request, Credentials);
            
            //  Compose the form
            string form64 = '';
            
            form64 += NERFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
            form64 += NERFormBuilder.WriteBodyParameter('json', json);
            form64 += NERFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
            
            NERFormBuilder.WriteFileResult result = NERFormBuilder.WriteFile('file', fileName, fileMimeType, fileBlob);
            
            form64 += result.Content;
            form64 += NERFormBuilder.WriteBoundary(result.EndingType);
            
            blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(form64);
            string contentLength = string.valueOf(formBlob.size());
            string bearerToken = NERFormBuilder.GetAuthType();
            
            //  Compose the http request
            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
            
            httpRequest.setBodyAsBlob(formBlob);
            httpRequest.setEndpoint(url);
            httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', bearerToken)
            httpRequest.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
            httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
            httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
            httpRequest.setMethod('POST');
            httpRequest.setTimeout(120000);
            
            NERResponse response = GetHttpResponse(httpRequest);
            
            if (!response.Success) {
                System.debug(form64);
            }
            
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I appended the code from url:
[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request%5D)

as appropriate and only added authType and token information with the changed URL.

I am getting an unexpected token 'NERResponse' in NERResponse and don't know what the means. all the `{` and `(` are paired.

TOKEN is the token i've created from the token generator (https://api.einstein.ai/token). I've spent about 36 hours trying to make heads or tails of this...but no success.

Thanks for the help

PS. If there are points that need clarification, I will edit this to clarify.

Comment: What was the error?

The quickest way to debug is to copy/paste code in an anonymous window and check the debug logs.

1. 'Authorization' & 'Content-Type' were not in quotes - I assume those are typos
2. Did you define "Remote Site" in your Salesforce instance?
3. Despite the changes, the request may fail since the form data is not correctly built - see the answer at [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request] & [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request]

Comment: see updates to my question. Thank you