# /metadata/deployRequest API deployment status: No package.xml found

Tags: apex, rest-api, deployment, metadata-api, package.xml

I'm trying to deploy an Apex Class using Postman and the /metadata/deployRequest API. I get a 201 response, but when I check the deployment status, I see the error "No package.xml found".

Here's the complete body of my request including the base 64 zip. When I save the zip as a file and upload it using Workbench, it deploys.

```
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
    "deployOptions" : {
        "allowMissingFiles" : false,
        "autoUpdatePackage" : false,
        "checkOnly" : false,
        "ignoreWarnings" : false,
        "performRetrieve" : false,
        "purgeOnDelete" : false,
        "rollbackOnError" : false,
        "runTests" : null,
        "singlePackage" : true,
        "testLevel" : "RunAllTestsInOrg"
    }
}
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="deploy.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

UEsDBAoAAAAAANlihVbc+9DtwgAAAMIAAAALAAAAcGFja2FnZS54bWw8P3htbCB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIGVuY29kaW5nPSJVVEYtOCI/PjxQYWNrYWdlIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vc29hcC5zZm9yY2UuY29tLzIwMDYvMDQvbWV0YWRhdGEiPjx0eXBlcz48bWVtYmVycz5IZWxsb1dvcmxkPC9tZW1iZXJzPjxuYW1lPkFwZXhDbGFzczwvbmFtZT48L3R5cGVzPjx2ZXJzaW9uPjU2LjA8L3ZlcnNpb24+PC9QYWNrYWdlPlBLAwQKAAAAAADZYoVWg7ZBRjoAAAA6AAAAFgAAAGNsYXNzZXMvSGVsbG9Xb3JsZC5jbHNwdWJsaWMgY2xhc3MgSGVsbG9Xb3JsZHtwdWJsaWMgc3RhdGljIHZvaWQgaGVsbG9Xb3JsZCgpe319UEsDBAoAAAAAANlihVZnWwVkoQAAAKEAAAAfAAAAY2xhc3Nlcy9IZWxsb1dvcmxkLmNscy1tZXRhLnhtbDw/eG1sIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMCIgZW5jb2Rpbmc9IlVURi04Ij8+PEFwZXhDbGFzcyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3NvYXAuc2ZvcmNlLmNvbS8yMDA2LzA0L21ldGFkYXRhIj48YXBpVmVyc2lvbj41Ni4wPC9hcGlWZXJzaW9uPjxzdGF0dXM+QWN0aXZlPC9zdGF0dXM+PC9BcGV4Q2xhc3M+UEsBAgoACgAAAAAA2WKFVtz70O3CAAAAwgAAAAsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKSBAAAAAHBhY2thZ2UueG1sUEsBAgoACgAAAAAA2WKFVoO2QUY6AAAAOgAAABYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKSB6wAAAGNsYXNzZXMvSGVsbG9Xb3JsZC5jbHNQSwECCgAKAAAAAADZYoVWZ1sFZKEAAAChAAAAHwAAAAAAAAAAAAAApIFZAQAAY2xhc3Nlcy9IZWxsb1dvcmxkLmNscy1tZXRhLnhtbFBLBQYAAAAAAwADAMoAAAA3AgAAAAA=
----------------------------BOUNDARY--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical data needs to be binary, not base64. In Postman, you can generate the body by using the form-data body type, and selecting the file to upload. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16015548/2132791) on stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks, I found that post, but I wasn't sure how to upload the JSON section separately from the zip. I saved the deployment options as a JSON file, selected it on one line, then selected the zip file on a second line. I get a 500 with the message "An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1413132269-140266 (1602089773)"

Comment: But before we go to far debugging this, I ultimately just want to implement this in Apex and was just using Postman to understand the API. Do you know of any resources instructing how to do this specifically with this API?

Comment: @BrandonDeMatteis Apex makes it hard, because we don't have native binary support. Most people use EncodingUtil base64Encode/base64Decode or convertToHex/convertFromHex to build the proper payload.

Comment: @BrandonDeMatteis Try [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/132135/2984).

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I did get this working in the end using this solution: https://github.com/nicolas1bruno/multipart-data-apex-request