# Callout named credential calls with a blob body

Tags: apex, callout, security, namedcredentials, externalcredentials

I am trying to launch a callout call to an OCR from an Apex method using a secured named credential with an external credential.

The HTTP request is a POST request with multipart body containing a file.
I am using this response to [compose the multipart body](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/how-can-i-compose-a-multipart-form-data-request).

Here a code sample I am using

```
    ContentDocument document = [SELECT LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = 'XXXXX'];
    Blob fileContent = document.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData;
    String contentType = vNHttpFormBuilder.GetContentType();
    String form64 = '';
    form64 += vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
    vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteFileResult result = vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteFile('file', 'test File Name.pdf', 'pdf', fileContent);
    form64 += result.Content;
    form64 += vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary(result.EndingType);
    Blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(form64);
    String contentLength = String.valueOf(formBlob.size());
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:TestCredential/api/publicapi/v1/transactions/launch?skillId=123');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
    req.setTimeout(20000);

    req.setBodyAsBlob(formBlob);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
```

But I keep getting this error when making the call. Origin of the error is the `http.send` method.
[image]

Even though the call seems to work just fine when replacing the endpoint with.
`req.setEndpoint('https://vantage-eu.abbyy.com/api/publicapi/v1/transactions/launch?skillId=123');`

PS: I have tried the named credential (the http call with 'callout:TestCredential') with a GET endpoint and it works fine.

I am suspecting that the script executed by Salesforce to inject the authentication token is failing due to some error with the blob body.

Comment: Without the actual error message, it's going to be hard to help you. Try wrapping the entire thing in a try-catch block and see what the exception message is.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox thank you for your comment. That's actually the issue I don't have much information. Even with a try catch I still get the same error. It says that the error is a CalloutException: script thrown exception originating from the ```http.send``` method.